# How to pass the selected row id to the subgrid's url in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I need to pass an extra paramter (i.e. the selected `row_id`) to the url that I am using for to show the sub grid. But Firebug console panel shows no extra parameter been passed. (of course the server side code is also not receiving it).

Below is my code,

```js
myGrid.jqGrid({
    url: 'server.php',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    width: 900,
    height:500,
    sortname: 'productid',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "JSON Example",
    rowNum: 100,
    subGrid: true,
    colNames: ['Product Id', 'Product Name', 'Supplier Id', 'Unit Price'],
    colModel: [
        {
        name: 'productid',
        index: 'productid',
        search: true,
        width: 55
    }, {
        name: 'productname',
        index: 'productname',
        width: 90,
        search: true
    }, {
        name: 'supplierid',
        index: 'supplierid',
        width: 100,
        search: false
    }, {
        name: 'unitprice',
        index: 'unitprice',
        width: 80,
        search: false,
        align: "right",
        search: true
    }
    ],

    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
        pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
        $("#" + subgrid_id)
                .html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id)
                .jqGrid({
                    url: "server.php",
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ['Product Id', 'Product Name'],
                    width:700,
                    colModel: [{
                        name: 'productid',
                        index: 'productid',
                        width: 55

                    }, {
                        name: 'productname',
                        index: 'productname',
                        width: 90
                    }],
                    rowNum: 20,
                    sortname: 'num',
                    sortorder: "asc"
                    data: {prodcutid: row_id}

                });
    }
```

How to pass the selected row id to the subgrid's url?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` [parameter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) has another meaning in jqGrid as in `jQuery.ajax`. So you should replace

```js
data: {prodcutid: row_id}
```

in the SubGrid to

```js
postData: {prodcutid: row_id}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the postData before ... but no luck :-(

Comment: @poddroid: you should additionally fix syntax errors and verify the test one more time. For example you need include comma after `sortorder: "asc"` (before `postData: {prodcutid: row_id}`)

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Yep I modified the syntax as well already. still not working. :-(

Comment: @poddroid: What do you see as URL in the Firebug now if you expand the subgrid?

Comment: Below is the url I see when I expand the subgrid,           http://localhost/exp/addacszend/src/server.php?_search=false&nd=1349886584214&rows=20&page=1&sidx=num&sord=asc.                                                          And I don't see any post data in the headers as well.

Comment: @poddroid: You have to debug your program. You should include `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` in your project, set breakpoint on `$.extend(ts.p.postData,prm);` line (just search for the line in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) and then on the `$.ajax`. The `postData` should be `{prodcutid: row_id}` in the line `$.extend(ts.p.postData,prm);` and it should be extended with additional parameters in the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Thank Oleg for all your replies. I came on this morning and checked that the modification I was doing is to one file (js code in smarty tpl file) and executing a different file that got the same code except the postData. .... Sorry ... for wasting your time ...

Comment: @poddroid: Not a problem! I was sure that you have some kind of problem close to this. In any way the problem is solved now and it's the most important thing. You are welcome!